# Implementing own authentication in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to implement my own authentication with spring. To keep things simple at first I'm going to implement the first step without any session, but an HTTP-Authorization header sent in every request.

I've read the documentation, many tutorials and of course searched on stackoverflow, but I couldn't fix it.

What I have is a filter (`RequestFilter`), which extracts the Authorization header and initializes the security context with an own Authentication (`AuthenticationToken`). Then there is an `AuthenticationProvider` (`TokenAuthenticationProvider`) supporting my `AuthenticationToken`. The filter is working, the authentication provider is not. None of the methods in `TokenAuthenticationProvider` are invoked. Can you help me, thanks :).

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    TokenAuthenticationProvider tokenAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterBefore(new RequestFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .csrf().disable()
        ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider)
        ;
    }
}

@Component
public class TokenAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TokenAuthenticationProvider.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    ClientRepository clientRepository;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        final String authToken = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        LOGGER.severe("AUTH TOKEN: " + authToken);

        return Optional.ofNullable(clientRepository.findByAuthToken(authToken))
                .map((Client client) -> new AuthenticationToken(client.getId(), client.getAuthToken()))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new AccessDeniedException(""));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        LOGGER.severe(authentication.getName());
        return AuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}

public class RequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(RequestFilter.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        LOGGER.severe("RequestFilter works");

        Optional.ofNullable(request.getHeader("Authorization"))
                .ifPresent((String token) -> SecurityContextHolder
                                .getContext()
                                .setAuthentication(new AuthenticationToken(token))
                );

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

public class AuthenticationToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {

    private final String credentials;
    private final Long principal;

    public AuthenticationToken(String credentials) {
        this(null, credentials);

        setAuthenticated(false);
    }

    public AuthenticationToken(Long principal, String credentials) {
        super(null);

        this.principal = principal;
        this.credentials = credentials;

        setAuthenticated(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return credentials;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return principal;
    }
}

@RestController
public class HttpGateController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(HttpGateController.class.getName());

    @RequestMapping(
            name="/gate",
            method= RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE
    )
    public String gateAction(@RequestBody String request) {
        Optional.ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext())
                .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
                .map(Authentication::getCredentials)
                .map(ObjectUtils::nullSafeToString)
                .ifPresent(LOGGER::severe);

        return request;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/status")
    public String statusAction() {
        return "It works.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Writing your own authentication scheme is rarely a good idea. Do you **really** want to do this?

Comment: Why not? Of course there are many implementations for different underlying systems like LDAP or OpenID, but it's hard to get an overview of spring security and which components can be replaced with an own implementation, so I'm going to do this from scratch. At least for learning how spring security works it is good practice, isn't it?

Comment: It is good practice or not quite opinionated. For learning experiences do it in a pet project and not a system you want to run in production also if you don't need to extend/change things then why bother, you only have the change to introduce bugs or make things less secure.

Comment: Please have a look at the code above. There are just a few classes. Are they wrong? How do I get the `TokenAuthenticationProvider` to work? That would be sufficient for now. I think that I could do authentication in the filter, too, but that isn't recommended. There are authentication providers which are chained and the first provider returning a non-null value will overwrite the security context token. At first I tried it with `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` but it didn't work, too, so I thought that an `AuthenticationProvider` with higher precedence catched it and denies access.

Comment: or have a look at https://danielkaes.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/custom-authentication-provider-in-spring/. I think I'm doing the same.